# com.android.internal.telephony error

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have been learning "Sim Toolkit" in android. I had imported the sample project from **[this link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_stk)**.

But this file needs another import of `"com.android.internal.telephony.cat".` i couldn't find any jar files or libraries. When i tried to import code of packages from this [***link***](https://gitorious.org/android-on-freerunner/platform_frameworks_base/source/a27353c1965911f69be8d02a01b15389189eab9d:telephony)

Im not able to done it. Help me to fix this friends.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It's a hidden library and not part of Android public SDK.

In future, go to this [link](http://developer.android.com/index.html#) and search for Android Java packages, method names, etc. If the result returned is not what you searched for, then it's not part of the Android public SDK available to developers.

Or, you can just download the Android source codes via the Android SDK Manager and manually search for what you want.